# MSSQL 2008 R2 Update Error

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, windows-update

I've been getting the following error:

```
84B20001 
"WindowsUpdate_84B20001" "WindowsUpdate_dt000"
```

I've tried just about everything but uninstall/reinstall which seems too much of a hassle.

I gave this a shot:

1. Uninstalled Logitech software and drivers for their webcam which had issues that was preventing SQL Server from installing because it would constantly say that there was a pending reboot needed to finish installing.
2. Cleaned up the registry where the Logitech install left junk that
   was making the OS think that an existing install or update was still
   in progress even after rebooting several times.

   (a) Find the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`

   (b) Rename the `PendingFileRenameOperations` value to `PendingFileRenameOperations2`

   (c) Restart your machine and then try again

What else can I do to get past this error when updating Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Which update are you trying to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first things to try when any update for a Microsoft product does not work correctly is to download it straight from Microsoft's downloads web site and try it manually. SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 is notorious for not installing correctly using the Windows Update control panel.

[Download the full service pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26727) that is right for your architecture. Once downloaded, install locally.

Comment: SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:


A failure was detected for a previous installation, patch, or repair for instance 'MSSQLSERVER' during configuration for features [Analysis_Server_Full,]. In order to apply this patch package (KB2528583), you must resolve any issues with the previous operation that failed. View the summary.txt log to determine why the previous operation failed.

Error code 0x84B20001.

-- was worth a try.